# add incremental column to select statement in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have the following sqlite select statement

```
SELECT myID,fname,lname FROM STUDENTS
```

I would like to add an extra column (myID) where each row will have an ID starting from 1...n. Here is an example:

```
[![enter code here][1]][1]
```

I would prefer to avoid the following expression

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
[PARTITION BY expression1, expression2,...]
ORDER BY expression1 [ASC | DESC], expression2,...)
```

The main reason avoiding using row_number is because i'm currently using **SQLite 3.17.0**

Comment: Why do you want to avoid row_number()?

Comment: Using the `row_number()` window function is the best way. Just needs a relatively recent version of sqlite.

Comment: i cannot use the windows function row_number() because i'm using SQLite 3.17.0. The windows functions were added in later SQLite version (3.25)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [AUTOINCREMENT](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html):

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENTS(
    myID INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT,
    -- ...
);
```

Comment: the tables are read-only. in other words, i cannot create or change the DB schema